# What is the standard parallel GC called in JVM crash dumps?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, crash-dumps

When the JVM runs with the -XX:+UseParNewGC we are getting an occasional access violation.
When we look at the dump file, we see

```
Heap
 par new generation   total 14784K, used 13689K [0x02bd0000, 0x03bd0000, 0x06950000)
  eden space 13184K, 100% used [0x02bd0000, 0x038b0000, 0x038b0000)
  from space 1600K,  31% used [0x03a40000, 0x03abe678, 0x03bd0000)
  to   space 1600K,  35% used [0x038b0000, 0x0393f800, 0x03a40000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 125324K, used 93541K [0x06950000, 0x0e3b3000, 0x34bd0000)
 concurrent-mark-sweep perm gen total 53900K, used 32283K [0x34bd0000, 0x38073000, 0x38bd0000)
```

I am assuming that "par new" would represent the ParNewGC.

I want to Google for similar logs where the standard parallel GC was used, does anyone know what I would see under "Heap" instead of "par new generation"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What kind of dump are you getting?  You can solicit this type of information from a JVM by simply doing a HeapDump with -XX:+HeapDumpOnCtrlBreak and send a control break to your process.  You can then analyse the heap dump file and get your answer.  Of course, if you're using Java 6, there is no HeapDumpOnCtrlBreak option and you need to use the jmap tool to generate the dump.